# Why Facebook SDK 4 is placed in your android project as another android project folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, sdk

Why is the Facebook SDK 4  imported in to your project as another folder of android project? Why not facebook release a JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

As I read from other topics, you cannot view classes inside JAR as easily as having it as android project folder (since you need to extract the class(es) inside the JAR). That's why there are not so many documentation for facebook SDK since you can look up into the class(es) of the facebook sdk to know how they function. Maybe that the purpose of facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK v4 is available on jcenter.

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

In the other words, jar file is available here http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/